# How to get full url from http request when there is # character in this url?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a script that sends an http request to an endpoint and that endpoint redirects to another endpoint.

Eg. `http://site/endpoint` redirects to `http://site/endpoint2#ABCD`
I want to retrieve (in this situation) `ABCD` (part after #), but it appears to cut and show only the before # part in `req.responseURL`. In the console after enabling showing XHR requests or in network monitor it shows the full url of the request.

How can I retrieve the full address of the redirected site? - How can I retrieve the after # part (Clientside not serverside)?

Example (To show that part after # is cut in `req.responseURL`, not actual redirecting)
[image: Console panel displaying "GET https://www.google.com/test#ABCD" and the corresponding URL with the post-# characters cut-off]

In web monitor after switching to raw content it also shows that the request was sent to `<url>#ABCD`
[image: Web monitor panel displaying request information, including "GET /test#ABCD"]

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', '/test#ABCD', false);
req.send(null);
console.log(req.responseURL)
```

Comment: The part after `#` is never sent to the server, it's just for use in the client.

Comment: @Barmar But I don't want to read it on server. I want to read it on client. Server redirects to a specific url with # part and I want to read the full redirection url on client side.

Comment: It should be in `window.location.hash` on the redirected page.

Comment: @Barmar ok but it is not as loaded page in browser but as XHR request